# Class and function same name?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm quite new to C++ and OOP so I'm particularly interested about one aspect. Moment when I define new class. I give it name without any functions in it. 
But outside of class there's function with the data type of class name.

I'm wondering about this particular example:

```
class point
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
};

point solve(line v1, line v2);

int main()
{
    point A = solve(_a, _b);
}

point solve(line v1, line v2)
{
    point a;

    a.x = 0;
    a.y = 0;

    //more code here

    return a;
}
```

I don't really get it how can a class name become an independent function with data type of that class and functions name to be different (point solve()). It's not a constructor, not a reference as it returns value. Inside that function there's another data type Point.

Is there a way how to write it more understandable for a beginner?

Comment: Class is just a user defined data type, before declaring 'solve' function you have declared class 'point' so the compiler knows about that data type. Its very similar as writing int solve(); Both are type of data int is primitive but point is user defined.

Comment: If you had declared the solve function before declaring class point then it will be an error as the compiler will have no idea of class point at the particular time.

Answer (score 2):

Well, find a good C++ book first. Perhaps C++ Primer.

I guess you are asking

```
point solve(line v1, line v2)
```

`point` is the type of returning value. So this reads like: `solve` is a function accepting two parameters, both parameters have type `line`, and return one value with type `point`.

Answer (score 0):

Class is just a user defined data type, before declaring 'solve' function you have declared class 'point' so the compiler knows about that data type

If you had declared the solve function before declaring class point then it will be an error.

point solve() function can not be constructor  because it is not the same name of class and 2nd it is out side the scope of class.